# Windows 8 Mobilebroadband Changing Logo in NetworkFlyout via Branding of CarrierControlSchema

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, mobile-broadband-api

I tried to changed the logo in the network flyout which is set via the DeviceMetaDataFile via the CarrierControlSchema. Right now I have a working Provisioning XML file and I added the branding tags.

Changing the Name is no Problem, that changes are displayed immediatelly. But my logo is not changed at all, though I have tried several ways to define it.

Right now I have:

```
<Branding xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/CarrierControl/WWAN/v1>
  <Logo>iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAAFiUAABYlAUlSJPAAAAA3SURBVFhH7c4hAQAgEATBgxxI+jcjA2/o8IJZs3bGWfumsfneFgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADA74CkABY+AmyW5KeVAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC</Logo>
  <Name>Sample Name</Name>
</Branding>
```

In this example I just tried to use a plain 32x32 png image all filled with red colour.

Can you please help me and tell me I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much.